# my webscraping code won't let my streamlit app stop running

Tags: python, streamlit

i am trying to build an app with streamlit , and in my code i want to do some webscraping , adding new data to my excel file ( csv file ). my script does just that but when i run the app it won't stop running
here is my code:

```
date = datetime.date.today().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
url = "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=BTC&tsyms=USD,JPY,EUR"
response = requests.get(url).json()
price = response["USD"]


fieldnames = ["date", "price"]


with open('data.csv', 'r+') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    csv_writer.writeheader()
    

while True:

    with open('data.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
        csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)

        info = {
            "date": date,
            "price": price
        }

        csv_writer.writerow(info)
        print(date, price)
    
    
        #date = datetime.date.today()
        date = datetime.date.today().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
        url = "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=BTC&tsyms=USD,JPY,EUR"
        response = requests.get(url).json()
        price = response["USD"]
        

    time.sleep(86400)
```

Comment: What did you expect?  You have an infinite loop with no exit, which blocks for a day at a time (which is silly).  How did you expect it to stop?  BTW, if you really want something to run once a day, then use a system utility like `cron`.

Answer (score 0):

Get out of the while loop.

Don't sleep for 86400.